# R loop quantiles unless

Tags: r, loops, quantile

I have a dataframe DF,

```
DF <- data.frame(Column1 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                             1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3))

q1 <-quantile(na.omit(DF$Column1), 0.25 ,names = FALSE)
q3 <- quantile(na.omit(DF$Column1), 0.75 ,names = FALSE)


DF <- data.frame(Column1 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3))

q1 <-quantile(na.omit(DF$Column1), 0.25 ,names = FALSE)
q3 <- quantile(na.omit(DF$Column1), 0.75 ,names = FALSE)
```

I want a function like that:

```
If Quantile1=Quantile3=0 
then DF$Column1 = DF$Column1 != 0 else DF$Column1 (remove that 0)
then we removed 0 and there is another case again Quantile1=Quantile3=1
then DF$Column1 = DF$Column1 != 1 else DF$Column1 (remove that 1)
```

I want this loop to run unless there is no Quantile1=Quantile3 in the Column1 values.

How can I write that loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function like this

```
neq_quantile <- function(x, q = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = TRUE) {
  na_pos <- which(is.na(x))
  y <- x
  x_pos <- seq_along(x)
  if (length(na_pos) > 0L) {
    y <- y[-na_pos]
    x_pos <- x_pos[-na_pos]
  }
  while(length(y) > 0L && all(diff(rng <- quantile(y, q)) == 0)) {
    keep <- y != rng[[1L]]
    y <- y[keep]
    x_pos <- x_pos[keep]
  }
  out <- logical(length(x))
  out[x_pos] <- TRUE
  if (!na.rm) out[na_pos] <- NA
  out
}
```

Then you can just

```
DF <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(NA, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3), 
  Column2 = 1:46
)
DF[neq_quantile(DF$Column1), ]
```

Output

```
   Column1 Column2
45       2      45
46       3      46
```

If na.rm = FALSE, NAs will be kept as-is. For example,

```
> neq_quantile(DF$Column1)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> neq_quantile(DF$Column1, na.rm = FALSE)
 [1]    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: ı have question, the function does not work when there are NAs? and when I write like neq_quantile(na.omit(DF$Column1)) it calculates false result

Comment: Hi @determinator, check my update. I think this one should work.

Comment: thank you! it worked.  as the result DF[neq_quantile(DF$Column1), ] ı want to write the column name as number of col not with $ as name , how can I run the function like that?

Comment: Something like this? `DF[neq_quantile(DF[, 1]), ]` @determinator

Comment: yes. But I just realized that the new code does not work if there is NO missings.(NAs) ? it gives that error : "error in while (all(diff(rng <- quantile(y,q))==0)) { : missing value where TRUE / FALSE needed

Comment: Really sorry about that. Check the updated one. @determinator

Comment: still gives the same error.... i think because of another case...

Comment: Hi @determinator, I updated the code. My best guess is that sometimes you have vectors like `c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)`, resulting in all values to be removed from the vector. This behaviour caused an error because `quantile(c(), c(0.25, 0.75))` returns NAs, not numbers. I added another condition for testing empty vectors. This is all I can do without any real data for further tests.